# How to optimize variables for a set of equations?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares

I have 6 variables that I would like to estimate their values based on 20 equations (the equations are stored as a list in f0). Does anybody know which library in python I could use to estimate these variables? Once the optimization is done, this is what I am expecting for the 6 variables:

```
# expected value for x[0] = 2,
# expected value for x[1] = 0.002,
# expected value for x[2] = 4000,
# expected value for x[3] = 2,
# expected value for x[4] = 0.002,
# expected value for x[5] = 0.002

def func(x):
    rl = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400]
    vin = 20*[480]
    ian = [22.381, 6.209, 3.4182, 2.0862, 1.7003, 1.5329, 1.4446, 1.3918, 1.3574, 1.3337, 1.3165,
           1.3036, 1.2857, 1.2793, 1.2695, 1.2552, 1.2475, 1.2429, 1.2398, 1.2373]
    f0 = []
    for i in range(len(rl)):
        f0.append((x[3]*x[2]*(376.99*1j*x[5] + x[4] + rl[i])/((x[3] + x[2])*(x[3]*x[2]/(x[3] + x[2]) + 376.99*1j*x[5] + x[4] + rl[i])) + 376.99*1j*x[1] + x[0])* ian[i] - vin[i])
    return f0
```

I tried to use least_squares as shown below, but the results are a bit off. Thank you!

```
res = least_squares(func, (0.1, 0.01, 350, 1, 1, 0.01), bounds = ((0,0,0,0,0,0), (2,0.5,5000,5,2,0.5)))
```

Comment: The function is returning a list of values. (?) What do you want to optimise ? - For instance, sometimes we want all values to be (as close to) zero as possible, but that is just a guess. When I enter your values I get output of a list around -500, so what is it what you want to get out of f?

Comment: I am trying to estimate values for x[1]-x[5], based on the equations listed in f0. I know the values of x[1]-x[5] beforehand, and I am trying to estimation calculated by the script with their original values to see if they are close

Comment: So given x[0]..x[5], you want to, without knowledge of x, find y[0]..y[1] such that f(y)-f(x)=0 vector Correct?

Comment: My last comment was poor, let me correct it. I have that my 20 equations are in the form of y = 0 = x[3]*x[2]*(376.99*1j*x[5] + x[4] + rl[i])/((x[3] + x[2])*(x[3]*x[2]/(x[3] + x[2]) + 376.99*1j*x[5] + x[4] + rl[i])) + 376.99*1j*x[1] + x[0])* ian[i] - vin[i]. The 20 equations change based on the values of ian, vin and rl only, but they are always equal to zero. Based on these 20 equations, I am trying to estimate values for x[0]-x[5]

Comment: I still doubt if I understand. Can you formulate in terms of some norm that has to be maximizes/minimized of some vector?

Comment: Sure! That would be original_values = [2, 0.002, 4000, 2, 0.002, 0.002] and predicted_values = [x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]]. If you do original_values minus predicted_values, element by element, that should be zero. However, although I know the original values, I don't want them to interfere in the calculations. I would like to estimate values for x[0]-x[5] based only on the 20 equations that I have. Them, once I found an estimation for the variables x[0]-x[5], I would compare (myself - not with the script) if they match with the original_values. Does that help?